# JavaScript dates - what is the difference between getMinutes() and getUTCMinutes()?

Tags: javascript, datetime

It seems like both functions return a number between 0 and 59.

Comment: But they might return different numbers.

Comment: Some time zones are not on 60-minute boundaries.

Comment: getMinutes gets the current minute on the system, getUTCMinutes() get the relative GMT minute

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a handful of timezones that are not offset by UTC by a multiple of hours, but have an additional half hour. You can see the list at [Half hour time zones](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html), and they include India, so it's not an insignificant portion of the world by any means. If you're in one of these timezones, `getMinutes` and `getUTCMinutes` of the current time will be 30 minutes different.

And there are two locations, Nepal and Chatham Islands, that have an additional 45 minutes in their offset from UTC.

Comment: And Nepal is 5:45 ahead of UTC :)

Answer (score 3):

One is based on the universal time (also known as GMT) one is relative time of the client.  So the base they call from is different. I did find some time zones do have partial hours, so the minutes can be different.

Comment: No, they won't necessarily be the same, [as there are time zones that are not an even multiple of 60 minutes from UTC.](http://www.geographylists.com/list20d.html)

Comment: +1. I wonder if whomever implemented `getUTCMinutes` was thinking about space time, since the only way I can think of to have your minutes different from UTC, asides a miscalibrated clock, is by invoking relativity.

Comment: I was actually looking into that shortly after I posted.  Thanks @Pointy.